# Why it shows an error instead of show the custom messages?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code below but there is an issue the custom messages are not appearing, instead it appears an error when the form is submitted:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request

Do you know what can be the issue?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Mail\Notification;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Conference;
use App\RegistrationType;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class NotificationController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $conference = Conference::find($id);

        $message = $request->message;
        $subject = $request->subject;
        $emails = [];

        $this->validate(request(), $this->participantRules($id));

        if($request->send_to == "participant"){

            $emails = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->where('email', $request->email)->pluck('email');
        }else if($request->send_to == "all"){

            $emails = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->pluck('email');
        }else{

            $emails = User::whereHas('registrations.participants.registration_type', function ($query) use ($id, $request) {
                $query->where('id', '=', $request->send_to)
                    ->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use ($id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->pluck('email');

        }

        if(count($emails) > 0) {
            $this->sendNotification($emails, $conference, $request);
            Session::flash('success', 'Notification sent with success.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            Session::flash('no_participants', 'There are no participants registered in the conference.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
    protected function participantRules($conferenceID){
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required_if:send_to,participant|email|nullable',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'email.required_if' => 'The field email is mandatory.',
            'email.email' => 'Email has an invalid format.',
            'subject.required' => 'The field subject is required.',
            'message.required' => 'The field message is required.',
        ];
        $this->validate( $rules, $customMessages);
    }
    protected function sendNotification($emails, $conference, $request){
        foreach ($emails as $userEmail) {
            Mail::to($userEmail)->send(new Notification($conference, $request->message, $request->subject));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should have `$this->validate($request, ...)`, not `$this->validate(request(), ...)`

Comment: Thanks, but same issue.

Comment: Please update the code in your question to match your actual code. What does the `use` statement look like for that `Request` symbol; is it `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the following line of `send()` function:

```
$this->validate(request(), $this->participantRules($id));
```

To this:

```
$rules = $this->participantRules($id);
$this->validate($request, $rules['rules'], $rules['customMessages']);
```

Because, the first parameter of `validate()` takes the `Request` instance, second parameter takes Validation rules and 3rd parameters take the custom message.

So your `participantRules` should be re-written as bellow:

```
function participantRules($conferenceID)
{
    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required_if:send_to,participant|email|nullable',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required'
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'email.required_if' => 'The field email is mandatory.',
        'email.email' => 'Email has an invalid format.',
        'subject.required' => 'The field subject is required.',
        'message.required' => 'The field message is required.',
    ];
    return compact('rules', 'customMessages');
}
```

You are trying to validate here without any $request instance which is not the correct way. To fix this you can just return the required parameters you need.

Comment: Thanks, do  you know how to have different message in the else of the if "        if(count($emails) > 0) {" instead of appear always "There are no participants registered in the conference."? If the user selected that wants to send a email for a specific participant (if($request->send_to == "participant") and the introduced email is not an email of a registered user show "There is not user registered in the conference with introduced email". And for the other 2 cases show There are no participants registered in the conference.".